# Include users custom post types in this query?

Tags: wordpress

This queries all of a WordPress users posts but does not include custom post types. How can I specify a custom post type for it to include?

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

global $current_user;
      get_currentuserinfo();

echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . "\n";

//The Query
query_posts('author='.$current_user->ID );

//The Loop
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
the_title();
echo "<br>";
endwhile; else:
echo "The user has not contributed anything!";
endif;

//Reset Query
wp_reset_query();

} else {
    echo 'Welcome, visitor!';
};
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters

`query_posts` uses similar parameters as `WP_Query` so you can do something like...

```
query_posts(arraY(
  'author' => $current_user->ID,
  'post_type' => 'custom_post',
));
```

If you want more than one post type to be displated the `post_type` parameter also accepts an array of post types.